# BackgroundWorker OnWorkCompleted throws cross-thread exception

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, arcgis, multithreading

I have a simple UserControl for database paging, that uses a controller to perform the actual DAL calls. I use a `BackgroundWorker` to perform the heavy lifting, and on the `OnWorkCompleted` event I re-enable some buttons, change a `TextBox.Text` property and raise an event for the parent form.

Form A holds my UserControl. When I click on some button that opens form B, even if I don't do anything "there" and just close it, and try to bring in the next page from my database, the `OnWorkCompleted` gets called on the worker thread (and not my Main thread), and throws a cross-thread exception.

At the moment I added a check for `InvokeRequired` at the handler there, but isn't the whole point of `OnWorkCompleted` is to be called on the Main thread? Why wouldn't it work as expected?

EDIT:

I have managed to narrow down the problem to arcgis and `BackgroundWorker`. I have the following solution wich adds a Command to arcmap, that opens a simple `Form1` with two buttons.

The first button runs a `BackgroundWorker` that sleeps for 500ms and updates a counter.
In the `RunWorkerCompleted` method it checks for `InvokeRequired`, and updates the title to show whethever the method was originaly running inside the main thread or the worker thread.
The second button just opens `Form2`, which contains nothing.

At first, all the calls to `RunWorkerCompletedare` are made inside the main thread (As expected - thats the whold point of the RunWorkerComplete method, At least by what I understand from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(VS.80).aspx) on `BackgroundWorker`)

After opening and closing `Form2`, the `RunWorkerCompleted` is always being called on the worker thread. I want to add that I can just leave this solution to the problem as is (check for `InvokeRequired` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` method), but I want to understand why it is happening against my expectations. In my "real" code I'd like to always know that the `RunWorkerCompleted` method is being called on the main thread.

I managed to pin point the problem at the `form.Show();` command in my `BackgroundTesterBtn` - if I use `ShowDialog()` instead, I get no problem (`RunWorkerCompleted` always runs on the main thread). I do need to use `Show()` in my ArcMap project, so that the user will not be bound to the form.

I also tried to reproduce the bug on a normal WinForms project. I added a simple project that just opens the first form without ArcMap, but in that case I couldn't reproduce the bug - the `RunWorkerCompleted` ran on the main thread, whether I used `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`, before and after opening `Form2`. I tried adding a third form to act as a main form before my `Form1`, but it didn't change the outcome.

[Here](http://depositfiles.com/files/1cu4o0493) is my simple sln (VS2005sp1) - it requires

ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF(9.2.4.1420)

ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI(9.2.3.1380)

ESRI.ArcGIS.SystemUI (9.2.3.1380)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=116930

http://thedatafarm.com/devlifeblog/archive/2005/12/21/39532.aspx

So I suggest using the bullet-proof (pseudocode):

```
if(control.InvokeRequired)
  control.Invoke(Action);
else
  Action()
```

Answer (score 6):

> Isn't the whole point of `OnWorkCompleted` is to be called on the Main thread? Why wouldn't it work as expected?

No, it's not.
You can't just go running any old thing on any old thread. Threads are not polite objects that you can simply say "run this, please".

A better mental model of a thread is a freight train. Once it's going, it's off on it's own track. You can't change it's course or stop it. If you want to influence it, you either have to wait til it gets to the next train station (eg: have it manually check for some events), or derail it (`Thread.Abort` and CrossThread exceptions have much the same consequences as derailing a train... beware!).

Winforms controls *sort of* support this behaviour (They have `Control.BeginInvoke` which lets you run any function on the UI thread), but that only works because they have a special hook into the windows UI message pump and write some special handlers. To go with the above analogy, their train checks in at the station and looks for new directions periodically, and you can use that facility to post it your own directions.

The `BackgroundWorker` is designed to be general purpose (it can't be tied to the windows GUI) so it can't use the windows `Control.BeginInvoke` features. It has to assume that your main thread is an unstoppable 'train' doing it's own thing, so the completed event has to run in the worker thread or not at all.

However, as you're using winforms, in your `OnWorkCompleted` handler, you can get the Window to execute *another* callback using the `BeginInvoke` functionality I mentioned above. Like this:

```
// Assume we're running in a windows forms button click so we have access to the 
// form object in the "this" variable.
void OnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e )
    var b = new BackgroundWorker();
    b.DoWork += ... blah blah

    // attach an anonymous function to the completed event.
    // when this function fires in the worker thread, it will ask the form (this)
    // to execute the WorkCompleteCallback on the UI thread.
    // when the form has some spare time, it will run your function, and 
    // you can do all the stuff that you want
    b.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) { this.BeginInvoke(WorkCompleteCallback); }
    b.RunWorkerAsync(); // GO!
}

void WorkCompleteCallback()
{
    Button.Enabled = false;
    //other stuff that only works in the UI thread
}
```

[Also, don't forget this:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result.aspx)

> Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler should always check the Error and Cancelled properties before accessing the Result property. If an exception was raised or if the operation was canceled, accessing the Result property raises an exception.

Comment: Checking msdn on BackgroundWorker I see that I specifically should use the RunWorkerCompleted event to handle the form. "You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events."
also - every time I try a simpler scenario it works fine and gets called on the main thread. Like in the msdn example there, or most of the time in my application.
It's similar to www.developmentnow.com/g/36_2008_3_0_0_1056508/Update-GUI-from-RunWorkerCompleted.htm

Comment: That's interesting... I created a test app (console app) with a simple background worker, and it fired in the worker thread. Perhaps the BackgroundWorker constructor has some magic going on that makes it change it's behaviour if it is created on a UI thread or not??

Answer (score 2):

The `BackgroundWorker` checks whether the delegate instance, points to a class which supports the interface `ISynchronizeInvoke`. Your DAL layer probably does not implement that interface. Normally, you would use the `BackgroundWorker` on a `Form`, which does support that interface.

In case you want to use the `BackgroundWorker` from the DAL layer and want to update the UI from there, you have three options:

- you'd stay calling the `Invoke` method
- implement the interface `ISynchronizeInvoke` on the DAL class, and redirect the calls manually (it's only three methods and a property)
- before invoking the `BackgroundWorker` (so, on the UI thread), to call `SynchronizationContext.Current` and to save the content instance in an instance variable. The `SynchronizationContext` will then give you the `Send` method, which will exactly do what `Invoke` does.

Comment: I am using the BackgroundWorker inside a UserControl (which is ISyncornizeInvoke). My paging controller doesn't know it is running inside a worker thread, nor does it care. It just executes a paging query.
The exception is thrown inside the UserControl, from the OnWorkCompleted event.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to avoid issues with cross-threading in GUI is to [use SynchronizationContext](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/gabrielschenker/archive/2009/01/23/synchronizing-calls-to-the-ui-in-a-multi-threaded-application.aspx).