# WPF CrossThreadException in App.Xaml with BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I have this in my App.Xaml:

```
public App()
{
    _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoBackgroundWork);
    _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BackgroundCompleted);
    _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    _splashView = new SplashView();
    _splashView.Show();
}
```

The `DoBackgroundWork` method performs some database setup, and then the `BackgroundCompleted` event closes the `_splashView` and shows `_mainView`.

However, modifying anything in the `_splashView` from `BackgroundCompleted` causes a cross thread exception, which is what I though background workers were designed to fix. I'm guessing this has something to do with the way backgroundworker's work in `App.Xaml`. Maybe this is a bad way to do a splash screen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no guarantee which thread the event handler of `OnWorkCompleted` will be used for execution.

See similar question [BackgroundWorker OnWorkCompleted throws cross-thread exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818767/backgroundworker-onworkcompleted-throws-cross-thread-exception)

You have to use the `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` methods to modify visual elements from a background thread. You can call this directly on the object whose properties you are modifying or use the `Dispatcher`.

EDIT: As per conversation with Adam

The `SynchronizationContext` has the desired effect for the `OnWorkCompleted` event handler to be run on the initial thread (not the BackgroundWorker's). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx. (See Figure 2)

If the BackgroundWorker is created and run prior to the SynchronizationContext initialization, then the `OnWorkCompleted` will execute on possibly the same thread as the BackgroundWorker.

Thanks Adam.

Comment: Right, I've added BeginInvoke to make it work. What I'm wondering is why I need this in BackgroundCompleted. Shouldn't this event fire on the UI thread? I thought this was the point of BackgroundWorkers.

Comment: @Justin984 Sorry, I missed the `BackgroundCompleted` throwing the exception. It is throwing because there is no guarantee which thread that method is going to be executed on. Logic would dictate it should return to the thread which has the event handler but this is not the case. [Similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818767/backgroundworker-onworkcompleted-throws-cross-thread-exception)

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know that. So even if the backgroundworker is created on the UI thread, it's completed event is not guaranteed to fire on the UI thread? I have some code to fix!

Comment: @Justin984 Yup, it's another thing we must code defensively for. I agree it sure would be nice if the `OnWorkCompleted`event would get executed on the thread the event handler was created on.

Comment: That's not true. As long as the SynchronizationContext is intialised, it will be called on the same thread the BW was run on. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx -

Comment: @AdamMills Is the `SynchronizationContext` new to .Net 4.5?

Comment: No. It was introduced in .Net 2.0 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @AdamMills So, if you create the BackgroundWorker before the SynchronizationContext is created then the `OnWorkCompleted` will run on the same thread as the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @AdamMills I updated my answer based on our conversation. Thanks Adam. I learned something new.

Comment: If you run the BW before the SC has been created, i believe the Completed handler is run on a threadpool thread (so the behaviour is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

The background worker uses the SynchronizationContext. This is going from memory, but I don't think it has been initialised in the App constructor.

Before you construct the BW check SynchronizationContext.Current is not null.
Also check SynchronizationContext.Current is the same before construction of BW and in the completed method.

If it's not, you'll need to move the code later in the process...
App.OnStartUp should be fine

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe this is a bad way to do a splash screen?

Unless I've misinterpreted your question, I don't think there's a need to do this to show a splash screen.  Just select the image and in the Properties window click the `BuildAction` dropdown and select `SplashScreen`.  Also, I think you can simplify your process by eliminating the `BackgroundWorker`, unless your data function takes a long time.  I believe you added it to accomodate the showing/hiding of the splash screen.

Comment: Our splash screen has a progress bar, so unfortunately I can't replace it with an image. The backgroundworker is because there is some database setup stuff that takes about 10 seconds to complete.